# Black space at the top of view after hiding UINavigationBar and UIStatusBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiview, fullscreen

I am trying to make a View (UIBubbleTable instance lying on the top of a View controller's view) fullscreen by hiding UINavigationBar and UIStatusBar. But for some reason black space remains at the top:

```
    NSLog(@"view frame before:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
    NSLog(@"view bounds before:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
    NSLog(@"bubble table frame before:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.bubbleTable.frame));
    NSLog(@"bubble table bounds before:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.bubbleTable.bounds));

    [self.view hideKeyboard];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    self.containerView.hidden = YES;

    [self.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.bubbleTable setFrame:self.view.bounds];

    NSLog(@"view frame after:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
    NSLog(@"view bounds after:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
    NSLog(@"bubble table frame after:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.bubbleTable.frame));
    NSLog(@"bubble table bounds after:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.bubbleTable.bounds));
```

NSLog:

```
2013-07-06 22:05:18.068 KIM[5085:c07] view frame before:{{0, 0}, {320, 504}}
2013-07-06 22:05:18.068 KIM[5085:c07] view bounds before:{{0, 0}, {320, 504}}
2013-07-06 22:05:18.069 KIM[5085:c07] bubble table frame before:{{0, 0}, {320, 248}}
2013-07-06 22:05:18.069 KIM[5085:c07] bubble table bounds before:{{0, 934}, {320, 248}}
2013-07-06 22:05:18.072 KIM[5085:c07] view frame after:{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}
2013-07-06 22:05:18.072 KIM[5085:c07] view bounds after:{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}
2013-07-06 22:05:18.072 KIM[5085:c07] bubble table frame after:{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}
2013-07-06 22:05:18.072 KIM[5085:c07] bubble table bounds after:{{0, 614}, {320, 568}}
```

How it looks on simulator: 
[image]

Why this happens, all frames and bounds seem to be right (0,0) ? What to do?

Comment: Have you tried to restart xcode and the simulator?  Does the same happens on the device.  I tried your code in a clean project and it works perfectly no black line.

Comment: Possibly do product->clean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this api:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

I once got the black bar when transite from different view controllers, and the above api saved me.